Converting ratio with range [0<x<inf] to range [-inf<x<inf]
I am creating some statistics, one of them is a ratio of positive integers, each in range [0<x<inf]; the ratio takes on the same range. I am interested in using a formula to convert such a ratio into a variable with range [-inf<x<inf], in such a manner that values [x<1] are converted to negative values such that, for example, a value of 0.5 would be converted to -2, 0.25 to -4, etc. while values [x>=1] are unchanged (1.5 remains 1.5). How might I go about doing so?

You want $0.5$ to both convert to $-2$, while remaining unchanged (like the other positive values)? Unless I'm misunderstanding something fundamental, that is impossible.

@TheoBendit My apologies, I worded it poorly. I've edited the question to reflect what I actually meant.

You are looking for a piecewise operator that is f(x) for $x \ge 1$ and $\frac{-1}{f(x)}$ for $0 \lt x \lt 1$

And the piecewise operator can be written in terms of Heaviside theta function, but doesn't really buy you anything except for looking like one single formula. But if you relax the type of mapping to something different than what example you have described, you can look at odd functions (which has odd symmetry about 0) by right shifting by 1 to get your required symmetry around 1

You are looking at something like the logarithmic function
